# Регулярное выражение PHP простое

Tags: php

Отправляется команда: `/send слово1 слово2`

Как мне поймать весь текст что идёт после `/send`?

Попробовал данный код:

```
preg_match("/^\/(.+) (.*)$/", $text, $cmd);
```

но он срабатывает если вводится например только одно значение, если ввести два слова через пробел - **php** этого не видит. Помогите как побыстрее пожалуйста. Спасибо заранее!)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
/^\/([a-z]+)\b\s(.*)/
```

Answer (score 0):

По разному можно. Например, такой вариант

```
preg_match_all('/[^\/\w+]\w+/ui','/command слово1 slovo2',$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Результат

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  слово1
            [1] =>  slovo2
        )

)
```

Если нужно получить целиком строку без команды, то так

```
 preg_match_all('/[^\/\w+].+/ui','/command слово1 slovo2',$matches);
    print_r($matches);
```

Результат

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  слово1 slovo2
        )

)
```